# Why does texture still show in texture statistics window despite not being obviously used?

Tags: texture2d, unreal-engine5, materials

I was working on trying to cut down the sizes of some of the textures used in my level, from the default of 8k, but after replacing the material used on a static mesh, I can still see the textures from the original material within the statistics panel, alongside the replacement 4k textures:
[image: texture stats panel]

The mesh only has one material slot, and its set to my new 4k material:

[image: static mesh properties]

If the stats panel isn't lying, I'm losing about 170mb of memory to a set of 8k textures I never want to have or use.

I have tried closing and reloading the editor just to see if it was a weird glitch, but it remains constant no matter what I try.

I'm using version: 5.1.1-23901901+++UE5+Release-5.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the Material using all of those to build the finished?  The naming scheme suggests that maybe one file is for normal map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, did you change the material on the mesh in a level or in the mesh editor itself, this matters as you would just be overriding by overlay changing it in instance or level.

Second, Did you try clearing DDC?  https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/derived-data-cache/

Is the Material using all of those to build the finished? As in for albedo, normal etc "sharing textures for LOD"?

[image]